# Condition for a finite p group to be cyclic

Tags: group-theory

The question is:

> Prove that a finite $p$-group is cyclic iff it has only one composition series.

I'm now learning composition series. But I'm not sure how to start it. Plz solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$ is a finite $p$-group and in a finite $p-$  group every maximal subgroup is a maximal  normal subgroup and so it has only one maximal subgroup $M$ .

In particular, since every proper subgroup of $G$ is contained in some maximal subgroup, every proper subgroup is contained in $M$.

Now, let $g \in G \setminus M$. Then $\langle g \rangle \le G$ is a subgroup of $G$ which is not contained in $M$, hence it is the whole $G$. So $G= \langle g \rangle$ is cyclic.